# How can I get latex to show an error message if there are too many pages?

Tags: errors, counters

I have a series of pdf files that I'm combining. I'd like to include as many of them as possible in the finished document, but for logistical reasons I cannot have a total of more than 50 pages.

Is there any way to make `LaTeX` stop compiling and throw an error message, should the page count exceed this total?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{My combined file}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=-]{cover.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{doc1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{doc2.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{doc3.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{doc4.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{doc5.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{doc6.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{doc7.pdf}
% More files included here

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use everypage to test and \errmessage to produce the error.

Comment: After some testing, \errsessage won't stop compilation.  \errorstopmode will, but it also produces no output at all.

Comment: I know I received help on here somewhere for this, but you can take a look at the `minp` and `maxp` keys for in the class I wrote for my thesis: https://github.com/vermiculus/smcm-tex/blob/master/smcm-tex/cosc/smcm-cosc-smp.cls, specifically line 134.  The basic idea was to hook onto the end of the document to make sure that we were in the range.  I'll post this up as an answer after work if you can be patient :)  It won't just stop compiling, but it will throw out a message (can be made into a fatal error *very* easily).

Comment: @SeanAllred That sounds like exactly what I need, thankyou.

Comment: @JustinT Done :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you including a bunch of `docN.pdf` documents?  Are they all completely unrelated to each other?

Comment: Those aren't the real filenames, just ones to show that different files are being included. The files are related, but clearly distinct - I need to keep the original files separate, and also have the combined file for easy(er) printing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the (newly created) [`pagectrl` package](https://github.com/vermiculus/pagectrl):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[range=2-3, report-as=error]{pagectrl}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-40]
\end{document}
```

Note that issuing a `fatal` error will cause TeX to halt, but this error will not be thrown until `\end{document}`.
I will be uploading this to CTAN later tonight.
Until it's available in the distributions, simply download the `sty` file and put it in the same directory as your document (or follow any other manual install procedure).

Comment: That does exactly what I need, thankyou!

However, for some reason the error message doesn't show up in the editor I'm using (http://www.latexeditor.org). The help text does appear if you type H after the error gets thrown though.

Also, compilation does still seem to complete even if you set `report-as=fatal`, if you just press enter when the error gets thrown. Is this a result of the error not being thrown until `\end{document}` ?

Comment: @JustinT Yes – by the time the error is hit, all the pages have already been finalized (which is why we know what `\thepage` is), so failing compilation at this step won't really change that.  There isn't a whole lot that can be done about that in particular, but I'll add an option to run this check on `everypage` as in the answer below.

Comment: @JustinT This isn't really possible, actually – see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/216346/17423).  The problem – as I understand it – is that we can't halt output once it's started.  `\msg_fatal:` cannot halt `tex` from inside a box (a basic unit of output).  I will have to remove the `fatal` style (and might as well remove the `critical` style) from `report-as` to quell any confusion.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I can (probably) manage without `fatal` and `critical` styles, I'll just have to be more vigilant at compile time.

Will this package be uploaded to CTAN anytime soon?

Answer (score 9):

Here is as far as I got.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{everypage}

\AddEverypageHook{\ifnum\value{page}>50 \errmessage{Too many pages}\errorstopmode\fi}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{My combined file}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{minitoc.pdf}

\end{document}
```